# ets.lookup is still returning old data for :tzdata_current_release, :release_version from 2019a tzdata file even though 2019b is released

Tags: elixir, tzdata

I'm getting error messages on a bunch of installed Elixir servers because we are downloading the `2019b` tzdata but the code to check the released version is still reporting `2019a` released. What triggers the updates to `ets.lookup(:tzdata_current_release, :release_version)` and why would it be broken? I presume it's not manual, nor my responsibility.

`loaded_tzdata_matches_remote_last_modified?/0:Tzdata.ReleaseUpdater.tzdata release in place is from a file last modified Tue, 26 Mar 2019 05:40:14 GMT. Release file on server was last modified Mon, 01 Jul 2019 16:50:25 GMT.`

I'm also getting this error, which may be independent and if so can be separated to another question. Just checking for thoughts.

> [error] error_info/7:gen_server.888 GenServer :tzdata_release_updater
>   terminating#012** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in
>   Tzdata.Util.first_matching_weekday_in_month/4#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/util.ex:73:
>   Tzdata.Util.first_matching_weekday_in_month(1932, 4, 7, [])#012
>   (tzdata) lib/tzdata/util.ex:329: Tzdata.Util.time_for_rule/2#012
>   (tzdata) lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:161:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:180:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:185:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:180:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:185:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012    (tzdata)
>   lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex:180:
>   Tzdata.PeriodBuilder.calc_periods_for_year/9#012Last message:
>   :check_if_time_to_update

Comment: https://github.com/lau/tzdata/issues/81 -- The latest release broke something. Update your tzdata version and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JustinWood, I'm not sure why my searches didn't find that. Sadly however I changed my mix file to 0.5.21 and mix deps.get reports `** (Mix) Package fetch failed and no cached copy available (https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/tzdata-0.5.21.tar)` I'll have to do more follow-up with Lau. This would seem to be the fix for the error, but not for the info message about the version mismatches.

Comment: @Sinc I just checked out `0.5.21` and it updated to `2019b` with no problems. Maybe that's a local issue for you - doesn't seem to be related to the original problem.
@JustinWood why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Because I do not like to post answers for "update your deps" type answers. Mostly because it may or may not always be the solution to the problem people end up here for.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip are you saying that the 0.5.21 fixed the issue with the release date mismatch as well as the code error? If yes then I"ll probably just delete the questions since as justin pointed out it's just a "update your deps" answer.

Comment: Download went better today. Will wait to see what happens the next time tzdata runs an update.